# Multiple items. One sold. One PayPal Buy Now button for other items.

Tags: javascript, css, paypal, checkout

I am new to webdev and looking for suggestions.

Basically I am planning to use an image map to sell some items.

Each image contains up to 100 items. User can simply click on what's needed and from that point I need to figure what will be the best option to checkout.

The easiest method and obviously not smart will be to create 100 paypal buy now buttons and basically place each button for each item. 
Cons - time consuming and space wasting because I will have about 100+ image maps.

Target is to have 1 checkout page which will know where the user came from and what he is actually willing to buy and somehow connected to PayPal Button.

Price for all items can be the same, no shipping price (it will be free) and no taxes. I don't want to have registration on the site.

Any ideas, maybe examples...?

HTML CSS JavaScript?

p.s. I found some topic about dynamic item name in paypal but I am still lost.

Comment: Would you like me to write you a small book on the subject?

Comment: LOL, I guess I am looking for something else. :)

Comment: My solution was to write a small API, that creates a 3rd Party Shopping Cart. Look at the first form example to see what you're dealing with [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/).

Comment: Thanks! Will look into this example as well. Didn't see it before. There is so much info about buttons/carts etc.